# Client cannot reach website hosted on Server when both are connected to the same hotspot

Tags: networking, client-server, hotspot

I've connected two devices to the same personal hotspot (e.g. using an iPhone's one). I did it because I want to create a local network where the two devices can communicate with each other and also both can access to the Internet.

One is the Client, the other one plays the role of the Server and hosts a website. The two devices can ping each other but when I open the browser on the Client and put the Server's IP address and the port where the website is served, for example 172.20.10.8:3000, nothing gets displayed and eventually the page shows the request has run out of time.

This issue happens also when using an Android device's hotspot. On the other hand, when I connect both to a normal Wifi network everything works just fine.

Does it mean there's some sort of limitations when using a Hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've found out that you need to set the Hotspot connection as a Private Network in both clients. Otherwise it will be set to Public Network and the devices' IP Address would not be visible by others.